Lone pair and hybridization
methane has bond angle of 109.5°, while ammonia has bond angle of 107.5° still they both have Sp^3 hybridization why?

Note that questions looking like homework/test/exam/lab tasks, posted without significant attempts to understand/resolve them, are explicitly off-topic on this site and will be closed.
// Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

It's not a homework or test or exam question or any lab task . It's a doubt that came in my mind while studying chemical bonding

And too I have tried and attempted it many time and tried to solve it

Then do not write it like if it was, when you have already spent so much time and effort on it. Bring a summary and partial finding you got during your research study and your own thoughts why it could be.

What is there to solve? There's a lone pair instead of hydrogen, so there's no way angle would be the same. And it isn't truly sp3, just can be approximated as such.

The central atom in methane (carbon) is bonded to 4 electron domains (places where electrons are stored), and so is the central atom in ammonia (nitrogen); that is why, as you say, they are both sp$^3$. But in ammonia, one of the electron domains is a lone pair on nitrogen, as opposed to carbon just having four bonds. Lone pairs repel electrons more than electrons locked in bonds do, since lone pairs aren't confined to a bond and are free to spread out more. In ammonia, the lone pair repels the N-H bonds strongly and pushes them toward each other. Since the bonds move closer together, the bond angle decreases from the 109.5 degrees we would expect if the molecular geometry was tetrahedral (like methane).

Be aware that answering LQ questions encourages posting more LQ questions.

I am well aware of the lone pair reason, however, as we know that the hybridization of CH4 is sp3, and sp3 has a perfect geometry, it should have a bond angle of 109.5 degrees according to the cosine rule. I am seeking clarification on how it is possible to have the same hybridization with a different bond angle using the cosine rule.

In CH4, every C-H bond is perfectly identical, so the four bonds are evenly separated at the corners of a tetrahedron. In NH3, a lone pair is not an N-H bond, so the four electron domains aren't placed at the corners of a perfect tetrahedron. It's like building a tetrahedron out of sticks, then putting a heavy weight at the top; it will squish down and no longer be a tetrahedron. A lot of very different things are sp3 hybridizied; hybridization isn't a very good determiner of many properties.

sp3 has perfect geometry IF and ONLY IF all 4 substituents are identical.
